# Replacing element in an almost sorted array with an element from another array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

My first array is almost sorted. I need to replace the unsorted element with the max possible element from the second array. The wrongly placed element would not be on the 0th or n-1 index. And if array1[i] is less than array1[i-1], then index i is the wrong index.

For ex:
first input 5
first array: 2 7 8 6 13
second input 4
second array 15 11 9 5
My result would be 11

however, If there is no possible element I could take from the second array, it would print not possible. for instance : 14 15 16 17 or if it has 0 element.

How can I fix this code?

```
   int n1 = s.nextInt();
   int[] array1 = new int[n1];
   for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
       array1[i] = s.nextInt();
   }
   
   int n2 = s.nextInt();
   int[] array2 = new int[n2];
   for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
       array2[i] = s.nextInt();
   }
  
   
    int temp1=0;
    int temp2=0;
 
    
    for(int i=0; i < array1.length-1;i++) {
       if (array1[i] > array1[i+1]) {
           temp1=array1[i+1];
           temp2=array1[i+2];
           break;
       }
       
   }
   
int temp3 = 0;
   for(int j=0; j<=array2.length-1;j++) {
       if(array2[j] > temp1 && array2[j] < temp2){
           temp3 = array2[j];
           break;
       }
   }
   System.out.println(temp3);

   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing Some changes in your code as shown below, it worked for the test cases mentioned in the problem above...

**1.** Suppose the value at index i+1 violates the sorted order then you should take temp1 = i and temp2 = i+2.

**2.** Find the maximum value in array2 which lies between temp1 and temp2.

```
// "static void main" must be defined in a public class.
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);      
        
   int n1 = s.nextInt();
   s.nextLine();
   int[] array1 = new int[n1];
   for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) 
       array1[i] = s.nextInt();
   s.nextLine();
   
   int n2 = s.nextInt();
   s.nextLine();
   int[] array2 = new int[n2];
   for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) 
       array2[i] = s.nextInt();
   s.nextLine();
  
   
    int temp1=0;
    int temp2=0;
 
    
    for(int i=0; i < array1.length-1;i++) 
       if (array1[i] > array1[i+1]){ 
           temp1=array1[i];
           temp2=array1[i+2];
       }   

   
   int temp3 = -1;
   for(int j=0; j<array2.length-1;j++) 
       if(array2[j] > temp1 && array2[j] < temp2)
           if(array2[j]>temp3)
               temp3 = array2[j];

    if(temp3 == -1)
        System.out.println("Not Possible\n");
    else
        System.out.println(temp3);

    }
}
```